# Can I remove apps that windows 10 doesn't natively let me remove?

Tags: windows, windows-10, uninstall

Is it safe to forcibly remove apps that windows 10 doesn't natively let you remove? You would think that something like Xbox game bar isn't essential to the o.s.... but look at IE. They went and made it part of the shell so if you uninstall it, you're boned.

I don't know what programs are actually going to break things if I remove them, so before I do, if anyone can confirm what locked / greyed out apps are safe to remove I'd appreciate it. I really don't care for Xbox apps because I dont use Xbox.

Comment: I myself need you to be more specific.  I bet others do too.  There are many components that can be removed from powershell that are as you describe.  Removing some of them breaks things.. some of them do not so there isn't a general purpose answer to this.

Comment: You can remove many of these 'non-removable' apps, but it will break certain functions. There is a LOT of documentation available only regarding this. Please show us what research you have done and what you have tried.